How to fetch the users' whatsapp templates using twilio API?
We are integrating our product to send out whatsapp messages through Twilio APIs. But we are unable to fetch the templates created on Twilio by the user. Is this not possible ? Suppose a client logs into Twilio and creates and saves a whatsapp template, we want to be able to fetch that template to our application using Twilios API.
This is what we tried

The screenshot shows an API key, please delete this question and rotate your keys asap.
For the answer: Please refer to the Content Templates API
